# Traversing 2 dimensional zip - python

Tags: python

I have a list(zip):

```
a = 1, 4, 7
b = 2, 5, 8
c = 3, 6, 9
```

I understand to iterate through this list by key to print

```
1
2
3
```

I can do this:

```
for result in list:
    print(result[1][0])
```

But how do we create a loop to print this? :

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

I've tried this:

```
for result in list:
    for i in range(0, len(result[1])):
        print(result[1][i])
```

But this prints all values for `a`, then all values for `b`, then `c`. How do we write the loop?

Comment: You're looking for `zip`, `for i, j, k in zip(a, b, c)`.  Unless you don't actually have 3 lists, in which case you should clarify

Comment: i am using a zip. the list is actually `list(zip)`

Comment: Then I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: You can't say, "I have a list" and then show three separate assignment statements. We don't know what you have.  Show the actual data.

Comment: You said a couple times you have `list(zip)` but it is unclear what that means because zip is a function. you could have `list(zip(mystery_meat))` but we need to know what the mystery_meat is. Or you could be using a variable called `zip` which would be very confusing since it'd override the zip function which is needed in the solution to the issue you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Your list is actually a list of lists isn't it?
All you have to do is simply iterate through the lists first and at nested loop iterate the inner list.

To make it easier imagine it as a matrix, so you have rows and columns.
For every row you have a list of columns with the actual values you want to print.

```
for row in list:
    for column in row:
        print(column)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have 3 lists:

```
a = [1,4,7]
b = [2,5,8]
c = [3,6,9]

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    print("%d, %d, %d" % (a[i], b[i], c[i]))
```

This returns what you need:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```